# ABAC - How is the PIP authenticated and authorized?

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, abac

What authentication method is commonly used for the PIP (e.g. certificate, login and password)?

Is the access of the PIP also authorized by the ABAC? I would assume that in most cases the PIP authorization doesn't require other attributes besides the request parameters and should be resolved without the need for recursive calls. Are there cases that r

Comment: Do you mean smart card authentication? The MSFT support it, you could set it inside the IIS and then inside the application ABAC is also support, since it based on the AD. Details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc732116(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Comment: No, I'm not talking about end user authentication. I'm talking about the authentication of the PIP (Policy Information Point). Wehn the PIP accesses regular API endpoints the service must be authenticated, too.